# How do I programmatically (via JQuery) set the content of the YUI text editor?

Tags: jquery, html, yui, text-editor, textarea

I expect this is a newbie question despite smashing my head against the YUI documentation.

I have a page with a YUI Simple Editor (called 'myEditor').  It hooks to a text area called 'posttext'.  New editing is fine, but the problem I am solving right now involves the user clicking on one or more existing elements, and putting that text into the editor for revision/resubmission.

What I would like to do is set the contents programmatically via JQuery.  I've set the value without an issue, and I can see that it's set in firebug, but I expect there's some method of the editor itself that I need to run to get it to redisplay (I tried re-running the render method to no avail).

Comment: Note: YUI is comletely independent of jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is named `setEditorHTML()`

See [**this example**](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/editor/switch_editor.html) from the YUI Editor examples, third code block ("Now handle the toggle").

Comment: That worked - ended up having another issue, and found out the hard way that moving around the YUI editor causes horrible things to happen (since fixed), but the function above was what I needed for this issue.  Thanks!